# Inserting TEXT in mysql database showing error

Tags: mysql

I have come to a weird problem. I have a text column in my table. I am inserting text taken from a textarea of html form into mysql database.

```
$sql="INSERT INTO mytable ( `username`, `firstname`, `lastname`,`about`,`email`) VALUES ('$username', '$fname', '$lname','$about','$email');";
```

about here is TEXT type column
And this is my textarea

```
<textarea id="oabout" name="about" rows="10" placeholder="Aboutyourself"></textarea>
```

If i insert the following text then the insertion works fine

```
I am a student
```

But if i try to insert the following text i am getting error

```
I'm a student
```

The error is shown as

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'm a student','abc@gmail.com')' at line 1

How can i make the change so that the second text is also inserted into the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue seems to be that your single quotes are not being escaped. In case you are using PHP this module will take care to escape everything that needs to be escaped in you input string: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php

Untested example for your usecase, the $conn has to be you mysql connection string:

```
<?php
$conn = new PDO('sqlite:/home/lynn/music.sql3');
$about = 'I'm a student';
$quotedAbout = $conn->quote($about);
print $quotedAbout;
?>
```

Basically you just have to call the `$conn->quote($someVariable)` for every of your TEXT fields that you want to be automtaically escaped.

Best regards,

Comment: Shouldn't this work $sql="INSERT INTO mytable ( `username`, `firstname`, `lastname`,`about`,`email`) VALUES ('$username', '$fname', '$lname',QUOTE('$about'),'$email');";   ? But it's not working too